# Correctly Allocating / Deallocating UINavigationControllerDelagate

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uinavigationcontroller

I have a `UIViewController` that needs to make use of the `UINavigationControllerDelegate`, specifically the `willShowViewController` method.

I am setting `<UINavigationControllerDelegate>` in my implementation, then I am setting the delegate to self in `viewDidLoad` (`self.navigationController.delegate = self;`). Then I implement the `willShowViewController` method and it works fine, however when the view controller is popped off the stack, there is a memory leak and my app is crashing. I've tried doing `self.navigationController.delegate = nil;` in both `viewDidUnload` and `dealloc` but it doesn't help matters.

What is the correct way I can implement this delegate for use in just one of my viewcontrollers?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`viewDidUnload` will not necessarily ever be called (it's mostly for handling low memory conditions) and by the time `dealloc` is called, the view controller is probably no longer contained in the navigation controller, so `self.navigationController` would be `nil`.

I'd suggest setting the delegate to `nil` in your `viewWillDisappear:` implementation (and setting it in `viewWillAppear:` instead of `viewDidLoad`).

Btw, you're seeing the exact opposite of a memory leak here. A memory leak would be memory that cannot be reached anymore and will never be freed. Here you have memory that has already been freed (your view controller), but is still referenced by a (dangling) pointer, leading to the crash. A real leak would usually not result directly in a crash.

Comment: Remember that `viewWillDisappear:` is also sent when another view controller is *pushed*, so that may not be what you actually want.

Answer (score 4):

You should either keep a weak (non-retaining) reference to the navigation controller or reset its delegate when it becomes clear the navigation controller is going to pop your controller. The truth is, in `dealloc` `self.navigationController` is already nil, and `viewDidUnload` is not sent when your controller gets popped.

Answer (score 0):

you should setting the delegate is self in your `[viewDidAppear:]` implementation and setting the delegate is nil in your `[viewWillDisappear:]` implementation.

Tips: you shouldn't set the delegate is nil in dealloc implementation, because when the dealloc is called, the viewController is popped from the navigationcontroller stack so self.navigationController must be nil.